# Only Get Data Where Column = 0 in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a column that has either 0 or 1 in it. If the column has 0 in it I want to display it in a view.

In my controller I have something like this:

```
def read
    @title = "Something"
    @posts = Post.where('read' == 0)  
end
```

For some reason it gets all the posts even when read has the value of 1. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct form is `Post.where(:read => 0)`

What your current form does is compare the string `'read'` to the value `0`. If we enter this comparison into a Ruby console, we can see what's happening:

```
  > 'read' == 0
 => false
```

So, that comparison is returning `false`. And if you simply type `Post.where(false)` in a console, you'll see that it returns all `Post` records, which explains why you're getting every `Post` object returned. In other words, the line, as you've typed it, is equivalent to typing `Post.where(false)`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format.  Your call to get the posts should look like this:

```
@posts = Post.where(:read => 0)
```

Try reading the [activerecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) and taking a look at the `Conditions` portion.  If you're specifying in hash notation, then you must use code like you would use when constructing a hash in Ruby.